# How to schedule a notification with changing data expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to make an app that utilizes expo's local notification feature and have run into an issue. I would like to make a notification that repeats every day at a certain interval with its data changing each day. I tried to use this syntax below, but it did not work as it only ran the function once, setting that value in stone for the rest of the notifications to come.

Expected (10 mins: "1", 20 mins: "2", 30 mins: "3" etc.)

Actual (10 mins: "1", 20 mins: "1", 30 mins: "1" etc.)

```
Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
       content: {
           title: 'My Notification',
           body: this.someFunctionThatReturnsANewValue()      
       },
       trigger: {
           minutes: 10,
           repeats: true
       }
});
```

In that case, I wanted to know if anyone had any idea on how to make a notification that uses the repeat property and has a body component that changes values each time it is triggered. The only other way I can think of giving a notification a different value as the last is scheduling 100+ notifications in advance, but that is not pretty nor practical. Any help or suggestions towards how I can accomplish this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In your component's useEffect or your application's App.js declare the Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener event. It will be executed every time the application receives a new notification. Within the asynchronous function execute "await Notifications.cancelAllScheduledNotificationsAsync ();" to clear the scheduled notification and call Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync again with the new message. The use of
repeats: true in this case is not necessary. Doing this, every time the application receives a notification it clears the one that existed before and programs a new one with a different message

Comment: Hi jcpaesf. Thanks for your reply! I explored that option but quickly realized the addNotificationReceivedListener is only called when the app is open, which just doesn't work for my app. My solution was to create a batch of 64 notifications at a time and then delete and recreate them as time progressed. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Hi again, how did you create this batch? Unfortunately I'm also having this problem and I need to send notifications when the expo app is closed.

Comment: Hi! I unfortunately do not have a way to send notifications while the app is closed, maybe your best bet would be [link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/) . The way I ended up doing it was creating 7 notifications when the user made a reminder, and then saved the current date to async storage. Now, whenever that user logs back into the app it automatically checks to see how much time has passed (using the current date and the date previously saved) and then if its been 3 or 4 days, it creates 7 new notifications. The only flaw is that if the user does not log back in.